# PHP code which connects to database not running

Tags: php

I have three files: `index.html, app.js, axiosfile.php`.

In `index.html` I call app.js by `<script src="app.js"></script>`.

Within `app.js`, I make the call `axios.get('axiosfile.php').then(...).catch(...)`

Within `axiosfile.php` I make a connection to the mysql database:

```
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $dbname);

if (!$con) {
   die("Connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

However, it appears that my PHP code is not running as I would like it to.

Some reasons why:

1) If in app.js, I were to change the filename `axios.get('axiosfile.php')` to a wrong filename (e.g. `axios.get('wrongfilename.php')`), I get a file not found error when I load the html file. So it looks like the call is being made.

2) However, when I change the database connection credentials in `axiosfile.php` (e.g. username, password) to wrong credentials, I don't see any error message (in the console or in the browser itself) displayed when I load the html file.

3) Whether or not I provide the correct or wrong database connection credentials, I get the error `Error: Request failed with status code 0 at e.exports (spread.js:25) at XMLHttpRequest.d.onreadystatechange (spread.js:25)`.

4) My PHP file works as intended when I run `php axiosfile.php` from the terminal. When I add "echo json_encode($response);" to the last line, the intended output is printed.

Some questions

- If my PHP code is working properly, where can I see the "Connection failed" error messages?
- If it isn't, how can I further diagnose what went wrong?

Full js file:

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#data',
  data: {
    records: "",
  },
  methods: {
    allRecords: function(){

      axios.get('axiosfile.php')
      .then(function (response) {
         app.records = response.data;
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
         console.log(error);
      });
    }
  },
});
```

Full php file:

```
<?php
$host = "hostname";
$user = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";

$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password,$dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$con) {
  die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$data = mysqli_query($con,"select * from table;");

$response = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)){

   $response[] = $row;
}

json_encode($response);
exit;
```

Comment: I tried a different permutation (mysqli_connect_error). I've edited my message

Comment: You're probably going to need to show a little bit more code.  Show the php call in your js file.  What is spread.js?

Comment: also, I might change that die("Connection failed...") with an actual json encoded response. axios might not be interpreting the response because it did not come back in json format

Comment: @dmikester1 I've included the js and php files.

Comment: I'm guessing that spread.js is probably a file within Vue.

Comment: Then it seems to me you're barking up the wrong tree.  Take a look at spread.js and your Vue code.